# How to correctly specify OpenAPI 3 Link object based on response header

Tags: openapi

I am working on a REST API defined by an OpenAPI specification document; one thing that is currently missing is the use of Links to define the connection options between endpoints, and I can't figure out how to specify what I want.

For example, imagine a `POST /widgets` endpoint that returns a `201 Created` response, and sets the URI of the created widget in the `Location` response header. My definition is currently something like this:

```
paths:
  /widgets:
    post:
      operationId: addWidget
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/AddWidget'
      responses:
        '201':
          headers:
            Location:
              $ref: '#/components/headers/Location'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequest'
  /widgets/{widgetId}:
    get:
      operationId: getWidgetById
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/WidgetId'
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Widget'
```

The OpenAPI documentation (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/) shows how to get the raw value of the Location header, but that's a URI, and the body of the 201 response is empty e.g.

```
          links:
            getWidgetById:
              operationId: getWidgetById
              parameters:
                employeeId: '$response.headers.location'
```

So how can I extract e.g. a GUID from `Location: https://my.api.com/widgets/3a32d587-56ca-4dea-81b4-01ed9cdf41c0/` to insert that into the `employeeId` parameter for the link?